# How to pass Tridion Content TCM URI to Javascript

Tags: 2011, componentpresentation, javascript

I have a JavaScript call inside the content like below

```
<a onclick="playVideo('http://xx/002A70/ChampionsOfChange/xx.mp4','Victor Dickson',tcm:24-17703); return false;" href="#">
    <img style="width: 200px; height: 113px;" alt="VictorDickson" title="VictorDickson" xlink:href="tcm:24-17552" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:title="VictorDickson" />
</a>
```

In the `playVideo` call, the third parameter is file path. I have a text file (closed caption file) in Tridion as Multimedia component and I need to pass that file path to the javascript.

If I hard code the file path as below, it's working

```
<a onclick="playVideo('http:/xx.mp4','Victor Dickson','/TridionMultimedia/tcm24-17703_Champions-of-change-George-Shout-Out.txt'); return false;" href="#">
    <img style="width: 200px; height: 113px;" alt="VictorDickson" title="VictorDickson" xlink:href="tcm:24-17552" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:title="VictorDickson" />
</a>
```

But I am looking to pass the tcm id. Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

Thanks everyone for the comments. I did the following to fix the issue

In the XML i added file as component link and in the XSLT i added a  tag to grab the xhref and passing that  id in the javascript call

XML

```
<CaptionLink xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="tcm:24-17703" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:title="Champions-of-change-George-Shout-Out" />

  <a onclick="playVideo('http://wpc.2A70.edgecastcdn.net/002A70/ChampionsOfChange/Victor-Employers-say-theyre-very-flexible.mp4','Victor Dickson',$('#George_cc').attr('href')); return false;" href="#">
                  <img style="width: 200px; height: 113px;" alt="VictorDickson" title="VictorDickson" xlink:href="tcm:24-17552" xlink:title="VictorDickson" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" />
                </a>
```

XSLT

```
<a id="George_cc" href="#">
    <xsl:attribute name="href">
      <xsl:value-of select="//Component:CaptionLink/@xlink:href" />
    </xsl:attribute>
  </a>
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't figure out what you need. Could you be more clear in explaining the problem?

Comment: I want to pass the content tcm id [ tcm:24-17703 ] to call the javacript. Here the content is text file.Usually i resolve the link as xlink:href="tcm:24-17552" .But i don't know how to pass this in Javascript call

Comment: But this is a component template? you have the multimedia (text file) available? It seems that you need to manage the tcm uri inside the playvideo javascript, but in the javascript there is no Tridion. You need to publish the multimedia component, and pass the file path to the javascript function.

Comment: This code is in Component[Content] . As i said before , i published it and if i use the file path '/TridionMultimedia/tcm24-17703_Champions-of-change-George-Shout-Out.txt' , its working fine. I am asking is there a way to pass tcm id instead of hard coding the file path.

Comment: @SivaCharan Yes ,this part is read as Text with allowed Rich Text formatting in the schema.

Answer (score 2):

As per your comments, you are trying to add all the UI design on Component. It's not a right approach.

Ideally you should attach the multimedia component on the actual component as component link field.

While rendering the template, you will get the Multimedia Component tcmId by using

```
Component.ID
```

On the Website, you can resolve the link and update the design with the resolved url.

### More details:

Below are the steps to have proper implementation

1. Add two fields on the component which allows multimedia component for

   - Caption
   - Image
2. Write a DCP or Component Template (CT) to publish both `Caption` & `Image` components and output TCM ID's in the form of XML

   Sample:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <Video>
     <Caption id="12345"/>
     <Image id="34567"/>
   </Video>
   ```
3. On the website page,

   - Read the Video XML
   - Get Caption and Image TCM Id's and Publication Id
   - Call the broker based on multimedia ID and publication ID to get resolved URL

     Sample:

     ```
      String binaryUrl = String.Empty;
      BinaryLink mBinaryLink = new BinaryLink(publicationId);
      Link mLink = mBinaryLink.GetLink(binaryComponentUri, variantId, anchor, linkText, linkTagAttributes, showTextOnFail);
      if (mLink != null && mLink.IsResolved)
      {
         binaryUrl = mLink.Url;
      }
     ```
4. Output the result on to the page in the expected format

Comment: If i understand correctly, I can add the multimedia as dynamic link and it will resolve the URI. But if i have 10 multimedia used in that component ,how can i differentiate and use it in <a>.If you could point me to any online resource to refer ,that would be great.

Comment: I will change the schema to read the multimedia component as a component link. Then access the resolved ID to call JavaScript method.

Comment: Shouting "This is not a best practice" doesn't take the discussion further. If something is wrong, please say what is wrong and how it can be done better. If you fix this, I'll remove my -1.

Comment: @Vani: Updated the answer with more details

Comment: @DominicCronin: Yesterday, it was midnight and don't have much time to give more details. Now I have updated the answer.

Comment: I can see you've added some details to your answer. If this describes your thinking well enough, perhaps you don't have any further need to invoke "best practice".

Comment: @DominicCronin: Publishing as DCP or Page XML and reading it on website is a best pratice.

Comment: Siva - claiming something is "a best practice" reduces it to religion. If you can't back it up with reasoning, it isn't helpful in a question and answer site like this.

Comment: @DominicCronin: Thanks for your inputs. For now, I'm removing the line.

Comment: I've removed my -1. Sorry to be difficult, but this kind of thing is important.

Comment: @SivaCharan Thanks for the updates. The fix i did follows your solution but i did it in xslt and xml.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing special about Javascript in this context. As I see it, you have exactly the same situation as if you were publishing a binary link in some HTML. (It's all text!). So if what you have on the CM side is a tcm id, and what you want on the CD side is a link to the multimedia resource, just use standard Tridion binary linking behaviour.